# How do I write a .bat file that will kill 8 specific processes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth driver (CSR) which would sometimes not connect to my headphones after startup, so generally I kill the processes in the task manager and reopen them to get it to work.

I found having to kill 8 processes and opening 5 exe's to be tedious, so I searched up and found a way to open multiple programs at once by writing a .bat file. Now I'm wondering, is there a way to get the file to kill the 8 processes first?

What I have in the .bat:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\CSR\CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack"
start CsrHCRPServer.exe

cd "C:\Program Files\CSR\CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack"
start CsrSyncMLServer.exe

cd "C:\Program Files\CSR\CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack"
start HarmonyUserStartup.exe

cd "C:\Program Files\CSR\CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack"
start TrayApplication.exe

cd "C:\Program Files\CSR\CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack"
start vksts.exe

cd "C:\Program Files\CSR\CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack"
start CsrAudioguiCtrl.exe

exit
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is `taskkill /f /im ProcessName.exe`.

So in your batch file, it might look like:

```
@echo off
taskkill /F /IM CsrHCRPServer.exe

taskkill /F /IM CsrSyncMLServer.exe

taskkill /F /IM HarmonyUserStartup.exe

taskkill /F /IM TrayApplication.exe

taskkill /F /IM vksts.exe

taskkill /F /IM CsrAudioguiCtrl.exe

@echo "Processes killed!"
exit
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I assume I can put it into the same batch file as the one I wrote into the post (under @echo off), and capital letters don't matter for /f /im?

Comment: You could, but that would kill all the processes immediately after starting them -- I don't think that's what you want, but I'm not sure. You probably want a seperate batch file, so that you "start_headphones.bat" and "stop_headphones.bat". (Don't forget to mark my answer correct if it is! :))

Comment: Oh, and yeah, command-line arguments (/f, /im) are usually case-insensitive in Windows applications like TASKKILL, but not so when running ports of Linux command line utilities. Just something to be aware of. ;0